# Link alexa custom skill and avs device

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

I designed alexa custom skill and avs device on same account, avs device integrated in android app. when i am using android app by logged-in from development account(build skill and avs here) then skill working fine, but if i tried from another amazon account then its not working? it says `this skill not set in your skill set`.

I read about account linking but i am not sure how its work?

how do you use my custom skill with my avs device in android app?

I appreciate any input. Any links and references are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Install the Amazon Alexa App from playstore.
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.amazon.dee.app

Install it and enable your developed skill.

Comment: thanks you for your answer but i want to design my own application and in that application i want above facility

Comment: You want to design the application find this very well built library.